# jQuery conditions in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu I am working with using current jQuery version.

I am trying to target a `ul` element based on it being `visible`, and `not` containing a class of `active`.

I can do the visible part OK, but how do I combine both conditions?

The statement is:

```
$('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
```

Comment: Like this `$('#menu ul:not(.active):visible')`

Comment: @Tushar: That's an *answer*, not a *comment*.

Comment: Worth a read: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Hey @Tushar, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#menu ul:not(.active):visible')
```

[`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) selector will exclude the elements those matches the passed selector from the `ul`.

`ul:not(.active):visible` will select all the visible `<ul>` elements not having `active` class.

Comment: You are correct. Will attempt to adjust approach to either use selector in `.filter()` or change source of Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!="value"]  to return expected value where more than single value at attribute

Comment: @guest271314 Attribute value selectors will not work when there are multiple classes, closest you can get with AVSelectors is `$('[class*="active"]')` but that'll also select `inactive` and `activeMenu`(_You've got the idea_). `filter` can be an **option**, but you've `:not` selector and `.not` function to exclude elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `.not()` method. You can use it with method chaining like so:

```
$('#menu ul:visible').not('.active').slideUp('normal');
```